# Check if file pointer is still valid in PHP

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, unlink, file-pointer

If you do use a simple fopen/fwrite() such as:

```
$ref = @fopen('/path/to/file', 'x+b'); // returns false if already exists
if ($ref) {
    fwrite($ref, 'A');
    sleep(5);
    fwrite($ref, 'B');
}
```

How can you check that the file pointer is still valid if some other process deletes the file during the sleep?

I have considered using a simple is_file() check, but that wouldn't say if another process did the unlink() then created a new file with the same path.

For reference, fwrite seems to still return true, even though the file has been unlink()'ed.

**Edit**: Just to clarify, the sleep(5) is just a random time, it could be just a couple of ms, in the case of a race condition.

Comment: I think your best bet is to `fclose`, then `fopen` and `fwrite` again.

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't keep the file open for 5 seconds in the first place :) Close it, and open it again later if you need it.

Comment: I agree with @BotondBalázs and @x3ro to not keep the file open for so long. But if there's not another option, maybe using `fstat` you can gather some extra information (I would look at the `nlink` field, but I don't know if that info is read when opening the file or read when you call `fstat`).

Comment: Though this is a much more interesting question than it seems. I don't know if `fopen` locks the file or not. If it doesn't, then nothing guarantees that your `fwrite` will succeed, and it doesn't matter if 2 microseconds or 2 hours pass between the two calls. I'm very interested in an answer to this.

Comment: I made some research. If it is absolutely necessary, you can explicitly lock the file with `flock`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós using fstat is a good idea (in my case) to ensure that the file the script created is still the same one (and not deleted and created by another process).

Comment: @BotondBalázs, tis the reason I asked (will update the question about the delay in a minute)... in this case I'm saying 5 seconds, but is could be allot less (I'm thinking race condition timings).

Comment: @BotondBalázs using `flock` will only work if other programs are trying to get a lock in the same file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just made a test, and it seems that `fstat` is the solution:

```
$fd = fopen("/path/to/file", "w");
var_dump(fstat($fd)); // shows ['nlink'] => int(1)
sleep(60);
// in a shell console, remove the file
var_dump(fstat($fd)); // shows ['nlink'] => int(0)
```

Comment: I think this is the most technically correct answer to the question, but anyone else who has this problem should have a look at the other answers and comments, as they all raise interesting points and solutions.

Comment: Is there a way to re-open the closed/deleted file with the same pointer?

Comment: @vlauciani no. You can `fopen()` again but there's no guarantee to get the same file descriptor (that file descriptor can be used by another opened file).

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform fopen() again. On linux system you can write into deleted file because you have still reference to it. When you close it the file will be finally deleted.

If process needs to wait I would close, then open file between sleeps

Comment: This seems to be the best idea so far... and the comment from @CarlosCampderrós seems to be a good extension to this, to ensure that the file that now exists is still the one the current process created.

Answer (score 2):

If you hold a handle to the file you do not need to bother that. Filesystem is taking care of that.

**EDIT**

Handle is valid unless you close it or script ends and **deleting** file is absolutely irrelevant to the validity of the handle and so is locking. One can easily check that by creating i.e. big file (1GB) and start i.e. fetching using browser and you can now "safely" delete it from other process. And this will NOT affect fetching even tools like `ls` will no longer list the file as existing. I wrote "safely" because if download fail, then httpd will close opened handle and then, if no other process hold a handle, it will phisicaly free diskspace. But it **DOES** as long as there's at least one reference to it, data remains on the disk (it can be easily checked by checking free disk space using tools like `df` - in sequence:

```
create 1GB file
df
start download
rm file
df
```

second `df` will indicate that discspace is the same as with 1st one (assuming no other file manipulation occured of course). Now stop downloading and do `df` again. Free space is now 1GB in plus.

Please note that Windows' FS won't let you delete opened file, but that's just a matter of implementation not technical limitations. Most (if not each) FS on *nix will handle this without any problem.

Comment: You do not understand the difference between locking and valid file handle. Please do some elementary research.

Comment: Thanks @WebnetMobile.com, but as the others have pointed out, the handle isn't enough unfortunately (and I can kind of see why).

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: Then I stand corrected. Can you point to some good resources about the topic? Or, even better, edit your answer to include more information so that I and the other people here can upvote it?

Comment: Ok - added more info on how to test that by yourself

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: Very interesting, thank you. What happens when two processes have a valid file handle to the same file (is that even allowed?) and try to write into it? Do they have to lock explicitly to prevent such collisions?

Comment: If there's no lock on the file any process can open it and it is technically fine. You have to however assume that filesystem will not put a lock on open (some may, but most won't). That's why `flock()` exists - if you need but more restricted/exclusive access, you need to lock it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. What if one process locks but another doesn't? Does locking work like the "monitor" concept like in Java or C#, or like in databases where if one client locks the table explicitly, no others can access it no matter what (OK, this is greatly simplified but I was trying to illustrate the concept).

Comment: @BotondBalázs in linux locks are advisory, so if one process acquires a lock a file does not affect some other process (that doesn't try to lock that file) trying to open, write or even remove that file.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós and WebnetMobile.com: Thanks a lot. Looks like I have a new topic to read about while my code is compiling :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a lot of precisions: fopen() locking depends on the type you opened the file as. `w` and `w+` will lock - `r`, `a`, `r+` will not (by default). However, if you really want to be sure that your file cannot be used elsewhere, the function `flock()` might come in handy.

However, if you really need to lock the file and do nothing on it for 5 seconds, I would instead question your design/implementation rather than find a way around it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the locking behavior of `fopen`. The PHP manual sadly says nothing about it (or I'm very bad at finding things).

Comment: 'x' is an extension to 'w', but doesn't seem to lock as you suggest... the comment about flock() seems to be the right idea, but in my case is not going to help (see other comments in a minute).

Comment: I have never had the need to use the `x` opening mode, so I cannot really comment on it. What I mentioned is strictly what I have seen in the past, and I tried not to infer anything else.

Comment: This is wrong answer (or you are not answering OP's question) -  handle is valid unless you close it or script ends and **deleting** file is absolutely irrelevant to the validity of the handle. You can easily check that by creating i.e. big file (500K, 1M) and start fetching and delete it at the same time from other process. And this will NOT affect fetching. And Locking is NOT for this purpose either.

Comment: An exclusive lock prevents files from being deleted by anyone but the owner of the lock.

Comment: Also, the validity of the handle is completely irrelevant - that's why `flock()`-ing it to an exclusive lock tackles the problem one step lower - rather than checking the validity of the handle, you're preventing anyone else from using the file. Standard race condition solution.

Comment: Try the following on a local webserver: $file = fopen("test.file.txt","w"); flock($file,LOCK_EX); and while the script is iterating (infinite loop it), try deleting the file. It. will. not. let. you. Locking is a solution to the OP's problem, and is the solution favoured by EVERY DB ENGINE to deal with race conditions. Checking your file handle will do naught, as if the OP is dealing in milliseconds, by the time you've checked it, its state might have changed again.

Comment: The question is about validity of file handle - locking is IRRELEVANT. This is **different** thing. On most FS you can delete opened file and the handle is still valid and content available. Please do some tests first prior giving wrong informations. And there's no need to check validity of the handle on local FS, in fact it should not be necessary on remote as well.

Comment: it will not because you placed a lock. Again this is **different** thing. And you did not read the OP's question carefuly enough. He, as you, do not know basics of FS - see *"For reference, fwrite seems to still return true, even though the file has been unlink()'ed."*. Why this happen is explained in my answer.

Comment: The OP's problem is that the file is disappearing during his `sleep()` time and how to ward off against this. If the sleep/inactivity time is in milliseconds, again, checking the handle will do **nothing** to help him.

Comment: `fwrite()` retuns false on failure, number of bytes written otherwise. While any non zero value evaluates as boolean true, sentence *"For reference, fwrite seems to **still return true**, even though the file has been unlink()'ed." indicates it all works fine. Only OP is confused why.

Comment: @user1800246 I don't know in windows, but in linux locks are only advisory: i.e., even if you call `flock` on a file, another process can remove it.